# How to recall method initState each time that I navigate to a specific tab in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm doing a flutter app with Cupertino, I'm trying to figure out how to recall method initState each time that I navigate to this tab (MapPage).

This method initState() calls other mehtod "initPlatformState()" who asks for the permission location and makes a request to an API, with this result I build a marker per each object's result and show them on the map.

Here is the code of the map page.

https://gist.github.com/GreyHat147/3ea92f4e962218893b84af667452b087

This is the ui.

[image]

Comment: `initState()` is called always when flutter build a widget. If you have to call `initPlatformState` method more than once, you have to use `setState()`.

Comment: Where should I call initPlatformState method?

Comment: When do you need it executes ? Once ? Every time you navigate to that tab ?

Comment: Every time that I navigate to that tab

Comment: then use initState.

Comment: are you using bmnav library for bottomNavigationBar?

Comment: initState alone is not enough because it's only called the first time. One thing you could do is pass in some flag from the bottom nav bar. Then in MapPage.didUpdateWidget you inspect this flag and decide whether to call initPlatformState again. I'm not sure but I think this should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For CupertinoTabBar you can do as below where create instance of state class and the without creating it again called it only on tap:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

MyHome myHome = new MyHome();
MyNearMe myNearMe = new MyNearMe();
MyMap myMap = new MyMap();
MyNotifications myNotifications = new MyNotifications();
MyWallet myWallet = new MyWallet();

MyHomeState myHomeState = MyHomeState();
MyNearMeState myNearMeState = MyNearMeState();
MyMapState myMapState = MyMapState();
MyNotificationsState myNotificationsState = MyNotificationsState();
MyWalletState myWalletState = MyWalletState();
int indexPrevValue = 0;

class TabBarPage extends StatefulWidget {
  TabBarPage({Key key, this.userId})
      : super(key: key);

  final String userId;

  @override
  _TabBarPage createState() => new _TabBarPage();
}


class _TabBarPage extends State<TabBarPage> {
  _TabBarPage({Key key, this.userId});

  final String userId;

  void _onTap(int value) {
    print('Value => $value');
    if(value == 0){
      myHomeState.initState();
    }
    else if(value == 1){
      myNearMeState.initState();
    }
    else if(value == 2){
      myMapState.initState();
    }
    else if(value == 3){
      myNotificationsState.initState();
    }
    else if(value == 4){
      myWalletState.initState();
    }
    indexPrevValue = value;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        onTap: _onTap,
        activeColor: new Color.fromRGBO(148, 3, 123, 1.0),
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: new Text('Home'),
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 22,
            ),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: new Text('Near me'),
            icon: new Icon(
              Icons.location_on,
              size: 22,
            ),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.map,
                size: 22,
              ),
              title: new Text('Map')
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: new Text('Notifications'),
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.notifications,
                size: 22,
              )
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              title: new Text('Wallet'),
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.account_balance_wallet,
                size: 22,
              )
          ),
        ],
      ),


      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                if(myHomeState == null){
                  myHomeState = myHome.createState();
                }
                return myHome.createState().build(context);
              },
            );
            break;

          case 1:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                if(myNearMeState == null){
                  myNearMeState = myNearMe.createState();
                }
                return myNearMe.createState().build(context);
              },
            );
            break;

          case 2:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                if(myMapState == null){
                  myMapState = myMap.createState();
                }
                return myMap.createState().build(context);
              },
            );
            break;

          case 3:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                if(myNotificationsState == null){
                  myNotificationsState = myNotifications.createState();
                }
                return myNotifications.createState().build(context);
              },
            );
            break;

          case 4:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                if(myWalletState == null){
                  myWalletState = myWallet.createState();
                }
                return myWallet.createState().build(context);
              },
            );
            break;

        }
      },
    );
  }
}



class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomeState createState() => new MyHomeState();
}

class MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('MyHomeState initState() called');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("test stream"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('HOME 1')
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}





class MyNearMe extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyNearMeState createState() => new MyNearMeState();
}

class MyNearMeState extends State<MyNearMe> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('MyNearMeState initState() called');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("MyNearMe"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('My Near Me')
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}




class MyMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyMapState createState() => new MyMapState();
}

class MyMapState extends State<MyMap> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('MyMapState initState() called');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("MyMap"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('My Map')
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}





class MyNotifications extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyNotificationsState createState() => new MyNotificationsState();
}

class MyNotificationsState extends State<MyNotifications> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('MyNotificationsState initState() called');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("MyNotifications"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('My Notifications')
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}





class MyWallet extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyWalletState createState() => new MyWalletState();
}

class MyWalletState extends State<MyWallet> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('MyWalletState initState() called');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("MyWallet"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('My Wallet')
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**If you want to use another bottom navigation bar instead of cupertino then you can use as below:**

I have created a sample example for you where initState() will call every time on tab change whether its same tab or different tab:

First of all import "bmnav: ^0.3.4" library in pubspec.yaml and then copy and paste below code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:bmnav/bmnav.dart' as bmnav;

Widget currentScreen = null;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    currentScreen = MyHomeMapSample();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

}



class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }
  int currentTab = 0;
  int prevTab = 0;

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    debugPrint('currentTab: $currentTab');
    return Scaffold(

      body: PageStorage(child: currentScreen, bucket: bucket),
      bottomNavigationBar: SizedBox(height: 58,
        child: bmnav.BottomNav(
          index: currentTab,
          onTap: (i) {
            setState(() {
              currentTab = i;
              currentScreen = getWidget(context, i);
              if(prevTab==currentTab){
                if(i==0){
                  MyHomeMapSample map = currentScreen as MyHomeMapSample;
                  map.createState().initState();
                }else if(i==1){
                  MyHomeWorkouts map = currentScreen as MyHomeWorkouts;
                  map.createState().initState();
                }
                else if(i==2){
                  MyHomeAccount map = currentScreen as MyHomeAccount;
                  map.createState().initState();
                }
              }
              prevTab = currentTab;
            });
          },
          labelStyle: bmnav.LabelStyle(visible: true),
          items: [
            bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.map, label: 'Map'),
            bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.cast, label: 'Workouts'),
            bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.textsms, label: 'Account'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    );
  }

  Widget getWidget(BuildContext context, int i){
    if(i==0){
      return MyHomeMapSample();
    }

    else if(i==1){
      return MyHomeWorkouts();

    }else if(i==2){
      return MyHomeAccount();
    }
  }

}



class MyHomeMapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomeMapSample({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  MapSample createState() => MapSample();
}

class MapSample extends State<MyHomeMapSample> {
  var myVariable = 0;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    debugPrint('current: MapSample: initState() called!');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myVariable = myVariable + 1;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MapSample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('MapSample details + $myVariable'),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    );
  }

}



class MyHomeWorkouts extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomeWorkouts({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Workouts createState() => Workouts();
}

class Workouts extends State<MyHomeWorkouts> {
  var myVariable = 0;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    debugPrint('current: Workouts: initState() called!');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myVariable = myVariable + 1;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Workouts'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Workouts details + $myVariable'),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    );
  }

}




class MyHomeAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomeAccount({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Account createState() => Account();
}

class Account extends State<MyHomeAccount> {
  var myVariable = 0;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    debugPrint('current: Account: initState() called!');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myVariable = myVariable + 1;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Account'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Account details + $myVariable'),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm working with CupertinoTabBar, I'm gonna try to implement the way that you describe, I appreciate you take the time to do this.

Comment: please post your CupertinoTabBar code, so may be i can help you

Comment: Here you can find it. https://gist.github.com/GreyHat147/d5cd5bb7acfcc414e75dd3ff7b225632

Comment: i have updated my answer please check it will work for you

Comment: It worked.  Your example was that I needed. Thanks for your input.

Comment: how can i do the same with DefaultTabController in flutter?