# Detect if user enters or exits a tab in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Hi is there any way to use WidgetBindingObservers to detect when a user exits or enters a tab in Flutter then refresh the tab after re-entering?

Im using it this way (refer to code) but it doesn't work so I need a little guidance. Thank you very much.

> My desired output is like that of Facebook's app, specifically the **NewsFeed** tab. When you **exit** that tab for a **long time** or you watch a video for a long time from the news feed, the tab will **autorefresh**

my **main.dart** code is this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}


class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  var lastloaded;
bool isInactive;
int _selectedPage = 0;
final _pageOptions = [
  HomePage(),
  CategoriesPage(),
  Deals(),
  ProfileAccount(),
  CartPage(),
];

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch(state){
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      print("p");
      break;
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
      print("r");
      break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      print("I");
      break;
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      print("D");
      break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Sync Shop',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedPage,
        children: _pageOptions,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState((){
      _selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/home.png",
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          ),
          title: Text("Home",),
          activeIcon:
          Image.asset("assets/home-active.png",
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          ) 
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/categories.png",
            height: 22,
            width: 22,
          ),
          title: Text("Categories",),
          activeIcon:
          Image.asset("assets/categories-active.png",
            height: 22,
            width: 22,
          ), 
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/deals.png",
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          ),
          title: Text("Deals",),
          activeIcon: 
            Image.asset("assets/deals-active.png",
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          )
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/profile.png",
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          ), title: Text("Profile",),
          activeIcon: 
         Image.asset("assets/profile-active.png",
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          )
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Image.asset("assets/cart.png",
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          ), title: Text("Cart"),
          activeIcon:
          Image.asset("assets/cart-active.png",
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
          ),
          ),
          ],

          unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[600], fontSize: 11),
          selectedItemColor: Color(0xFFEF5021),
          selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12),
          ),
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are your pages in separate file (.dart) ?

Comment: @Naveen Avidi yes

Comment: It may help you ! https://stackoverflow.com/a/55974774/5557479

Answer (score 1):

in your child page (those elements in your page options list)

add your function to your initState for the "On enter" and add your fnction to your dispose for the "On leave"

Example

HomePage.dart

```
class _homeState extends State<HomePage>{
   @override
   void initState(){
     if(this.mounted){
        *your_function_here*
     }
     super.initState();
   }

   @override
   void dispose(){
      if(this.mounted){
        *your_onleave_function_here*
     }
      super.dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: What js this functions that you are talking about that I should add to my child pages? (im kimda confused)

Comment: the one that refreshes, you dont need WidgetsBindingObserver